# how to display custom error page in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

i already set up log streamer in .htaccess, and disabled logs @ production so logs comes the way i want to see them. But how to display any custom error screen for visitors? Now i got blank page. Any sugestions?

Cheers,
ad

Answer (score 0):

Do a `try{...}catch{...}` when a error occurs and then set a custom error message. You should have something like this:

**Controller**

```
try
{
   // stuff
}
catch(Zend_Exception $Ex)
{
   $this->view->Error = 'My custom error';
}
```

**View**

```
if ($this->Error !== null)
   echo 'Error: ' . $this->Error;
```

Comment: i would preffer something more global like setting special layout and rendering it while error/exception/notice occures.

Comment: @AndrzejDziekoński In this case you can edit the behavior of ErrorController.php

Comment: i kinda did it but i cant see my error view. I got blank page when i disable loging errors and php output when i enable it.